Amaryllis blooms - eaten
My red amaryllis blooms are eaten even before they open and then after too. I've tried slug bait but it disappears and the blooms are still munched, from the outside. What could be eating the snail/slug bait and then crawls up to the bloom to eat that too?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
